# ActiveRecord with two belongs_to of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So we have an model with two belongs_to lines for the same model, but different columns.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person1, class_name: 'Person'
  belongs_to :person2, class_name: 'Person'
end
```

When I use `.includes(:person1, :person2)` this generates the following SQL.

```
SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" IN (1)
SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" IN (2)
```

How can I do `SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" IN (1,2)` instead?

Comment: active record `includes` will issue one sql query per association and person1 and person2 are different associations, even though they are the same database table/model; based on the queries logged I am guessing you only have 1 thing with 1 person1 and 1 person2 add more data and the number of queries should NOT go up

Comment: Thanks - so its not possible to combine those and have ActiveRecord resolve them on the Rails side? I'd have to build an association table or something I guess.

Comment: As far as I know there is no default way in rails. If I were you I would not worry about the 1 extra query. You definitely want to avoid N+1 queries - but this doesn't appear to be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just eager load the class name like so:

```
Thing.includes(:person).where(.....).references(:person)
```

Comment: Seems to get `Association named 'person' was not found on Thing; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: Do you have the association correct in your schema? You should have a `person_id` on `Thing` if so. Additionally, make sure the association is correct in the opposite direction (on `Person`) via `has_many :things, inverse_of: :person`

Comment: No. You reference the associated class in order to do an eager load. New Rails update specifies that if you reference it within your query (e.g. within the `#where` clause), you also need to append the `#references` method to the end of the query, to tell Rails you actually used it.

Comment: So in this case, the `#references` is only necessary if you were to actually use a reference to the `Person` class in the query, which I'm assuming he'll need to do. The only thing that matters for eager-loading is the class name :)

Comment: Here's a link for you: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations

Comment: I'm not sure if I am understanding.

Thing has two relationships to people. If I do Thing.includes(:person1, :person2) I get two select statements. Not one.

Comment: The thing to remember, though, is that you eager load entire tables. The fact that you have two relationships to the same table is irrelevant--it only matters that you eager load that table.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to implement this. If I run Thing.includes(:person) or Thing.includes(:people) I get `Association named 'person' was not found` do you have an example of this working?

Comment: Does your `Thing` table have the correct association with `Person`? It should have a `person_id` column.

Comment: I figured it out - thanks for the help. References was the missing component. I found this question very helpful: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html